# How to send data from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
$('myBtn').on("click",function(){
var parent= $(this).parent();// will give you the Parent Object of the button, that has       been clicked
});
```

I need to send var parent to php so it knows where to display the html data (in the correct are div/class, how would i do this.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I think Ajax can solve your problem.

Comment: should create an ajax function that sends the var to php?

Comment: +1 on the ajax - you should have a look at the jQuery ajax command.  It's really easy to use and does exactly what you want.  The jQuery docs should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood how AJAX works. PHP cannot edit HTML contents in user's browser once the page has been rendered. Instead, you request needed info from PHP with Javascript (AJAX) and then add returned data to the `myBtn`'s `parent` with Javascript. Read more about jquery ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Songo I agree. [Ajax is really great and does all things](http://krannix.soup.io/post/55730616/jQuery-Its-really-great-and-does-all)

Comment: I suppose the OP has not clear that `parent` is a *live object* inside the browser, but over HTTP just pass strings, not objects. +1 for me for [Quentin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521893/573034).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that "You can't".

Communication between the browser (where your JS is running) and the server (where the PHP is running) is handled via HTTP. If you want to send a JavaScript object then you have to serialise it to a string and deserialise it at the other end. There is no sane way to represent an HTMLElementNode (or a jQuery object that wraps on) in that process (not least because PHP doesn't usually represent HTML in a DOM and when it does it won't be the same DOM instance as the browser is using).

Usually in this type of situation, you would request some data from PHP (possibly using one of jQuery's [ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) and then use JavaScript to turn it into DOM elements and insert it into the document.

Answer (score 2):

Try [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and Ajax ([XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)) as the "client to server" mechanism

JavaScript is evaluated on client-side, when PHP is server side. You don't have trivial way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the html data is not already generated, you would have to make a new request to the server, preferrably by the jQuery `$.get` function, then pass the output (again via jQuery) to the `parent` element.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jquery and use $.ajax for this purpose

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "yourPHPPage.php",
data: "parentvar="+parent,
```

//parent is a javascript variable

```
success: function(msg){


//Message received from server,
    // if you would write some code in echo there, like echo "hello";
    // you would get that in msg.


}
```

});

to access this variable on php, use $_POST["parentvar"];
You can also send multiple values by concatinating them with & operator.
Like `data:"parentVar="+parent+"&name=atif&age=23"`; etc

Please let me know if further help needed.

Further help on
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Stringifying a jQuery object isn't going to give you anything useful to send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't pass a DOM object directly to the server -- there's too much information stored for it to be practical.  You could send the HTML of the object though.

Here's an example that sends the HTML to the server.  You would process it, but we just echo it back.

http://jsfiddle.net/hLD4F/

Try clicking on any of the buttons, and it will send a request.  In PHP you could access this information via `$_POST['html']`.